# Generic Orderby LINQ

Tags: linq, generics, sql-order-by

I have a generic repository method to enable server side paging:

```
public virtual IEnumerable<T> GetList(out int totalPages, Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter = null,
                                            Expression<Func<T, object>> orderby = null,
                                            bool ascending = true,
                                            string includeProperties = "",
                                            int pageSize = 10, int pageNumber = 1)
    {
        IQueryable<T> query = c.Set<T>();
        if (filter != null)
        {
            query = query.Where(filter);
        }

        query = includeProperties.Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Aggregate(query, (current, includeProp) => current.Include(includeProp));

        if (orderby != null)
        {
            query = @ascending ? query.OrderBy(@orderby) : query.OrderByDescending(@orderby);
        }
        else
        {
            query = @ascending ? query.OrderBy(o => o.Id) : query.OrderByDescending(o => o.Id);
        }

        //totalPages = (int) Math.Ceiling((double)(Queryable.Count(query) / pageSize));
        totalPages = 1;

        if (pageSize > 0)
        {
            var skip = 0;
            var take = pageSize;
            if (pageNumber > 1)
            {
                skip = (pageNumber - 1) * pageSize;
                take = pageSize + skip;
            }
            query = query.Take(take);
            query = query.Skip(skip);
        }
        return query.ToList();
    }
```

T is a base class inherited by my entities
I call this repository method from my service. and i call my service from my controller. 
Now from my controller how do i create my orderby expression so that i can pass any column name?

What i've tried so far (found on stackoverflow):

```
           var _OrderByProperty = typeof(Year).GetProperty("Id");
        var _OrderByParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Year), "x");            
        var _OrderByBody = Expression.Property(_OrderByParameter, _OrderByProperty.Name);
        var _OrderByConverted = Expression.Convert(_OrderByBody, typeof(Object));
        var _OrderByLambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<Year, object>>
            (_OrderByConverted, _OrderByParameter);           

        var list = s.GetList(orderby: _OrderByLambda, totalPages: out totalPages, pageNumber: pageNumber, pageSize: pageSize, ascending: isAsc);
```

i'm getting the error

Unable to cast the type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.Object'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types.

Comment: Does your method signature have to stay the same? If you could change it to have two generic type parameters, one of which is the type of the ordering key, that would make it a lot simpler.

Comment: Can you exemplify please?

Comment: Well instead of a non-generic `GetList`, it could be `GetList<TKey>` and take an `Expression<Func<T, TKey>>`. (I hadn't spotted that the method was originally non-generic, using `T` from the type. Basically this is a matter of making it generic with one type parameter: the ordering key.